# Visual Studio 2019 Project Export Template change Output Location

Tags: templates, export

I am trying to do an export of my project template, and the output location is outdated and greyed out.  I can't save to this folder.  I have gone in to Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Locations and have set my new locations, but the export wizard isn't using this setup.  Is there another configuration setting in VS 2019 that I am missing for the export wizard template to export the file to?
I tried running the export with the old, and noticed I had 2 exports created, one in the old folder, which I can't use, and the other in my new location.  I rebooted my machine to see if the new location would be the only one, but same result.

Comment: Dealing with the same issue :/

Answer (score -1):

You can change the known location for user templates in Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Locations.